# List Comprehension - Conditional

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For these 2 lists:

```
A=['3.40', '4.00', '151.00', '8.00', '81.00', '23.00', '17.00', '8.50', '5.00', '151.00', 'SCR', 'SCR', '13.00']
B=['11', '5', '2', '4', '6', '9', '7', '8', '10', '1', '12', '10', '3']
```

The desired output is:

```
C=['11', '5', '2', '4', '6', '9', '7', '8', '10', '1', '3']
```

So - list 'A' and list 'B' are the same length. List 'C' is the same as list 'B' - but does not have the values where 'SCR' exists in list 'A'.

My attempt at this is:

```
C = [x for x in B if x in A!='SCR']
```

Thankyou

Comment: `c = [b for a, b in zip(A, B) if a != "SCR]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just zip them together:

```py
C = [b for a,b in zip(A,B) if a != 'SCR']
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I think you're trying to accomplish, I think you would need this:

```py
C = [B[x] for x in range(len(B)) if A[x] != 'SCR']
```

Comment: May be worth reading: [Never use "for i in range(len(sequence))](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Basic-Never-use-for-i-in-range-len-sequence) and [Loop like a native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward using the built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
[x for (idx, x) in enumerate(B) if A[idx] == 'SCR']
```